# Is Azure ServiceBusQueueTrigger is comapatble with Tibco EMS?

Tags: azure, spring-boot, tibco-ems

If ServiceBusQueueTrigger works with Tibco EMS then how can we define the connection details of tibco EMS inside ServiceBusQueueTrigger method? Suppose the method is , it's written in Springboot and I am trying to read message from EMS queue . Does this connection parameter only accepts the AzureServiceBusConnection?

```
public void serviceBusProcess( @ServiceBusQueueTrigger(name = "msg", queueName = "myQueuename",connection = "????????") String message,
                final ExecutionContext context)
         {
                System.out.println("Received from 1st receiver using ServicebusTrigger<" + message +">");
            
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

ServiceBusQueueTrigger only supports Azure Service Bus Connection string, you cannot specify Tibco EMS connection string in it

Comment: Can I establish tibco TCP connection in Azure web app using spring boot? Corrently I am getting below error in log stream "Unable to contact telemetry service: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"

Comment: depends, you're trying a kind of listener to a particular port, then no. It will be only available using Service Fabric or Vms